# Выравнивание структуры

Tags: c++, c

Есть структура _dem_ram_data_. Она должна занимать в памяти 16 байт, но я получаю 21 байт. Использую на 64 разрядной системе.

```
#include <iostream>
typedef unsigned long       ViUInt32;
typedef long                ViInt32;
typedef unsigned char       ViUInt8;
typedef unsigned long long  ViUInt64;
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct _dem_ram_data_{ 
    union {
        struct {
            ViUInt32 errors     : 32;
            ViInt32  addr       : 27;
            ViUInt8 _reserve    : 2;    
            ViUInt8 dataType    : 2;
            ViUInt8 graphEna    : 1;
        } vecAddr;
        struct {
            ViUInt64 tact       : 42;
            ViUInt32 _reserve   : 19;   
            ViUInt8 dataType    : 2;
            ViUInt8 graphEna    : 1;
        } tact;
         ViUInt64 d;
    } demData;
    ViUInt32 cpl;
    ViUInt32 cph;
} DemRamData, *PDemRamData;  
#pragma pack(pop)
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(DemRamData) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typedef long ViInt32;` - по непонятной причине тут предполагается, что sizeof(long) будет 4. Вместо этих самопальных алиасов используйте стандартные целочисленные типы фиксированной длинны `std::int32_t` и т.п. Также имеет смыл избавиться от безымянных классов.

Comment: Эти алиасы используются в проекте. Нужны именно они.

Comment: так long и занимает 4 байта. Разве не так должно быть?

Comment: @user370984 https://godbolt.org/z/Nw7pn- Это в vc++ long обычно только 4 байта

Comment: Я заменил алиасы на стандартные типы и все равно получаю 21 байт.

Comment: Использую MinGW64-bit

Comment: попробуйте вытащить наружу структуры и объединение и посмотреть их размеры вне общей структуры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена заменой разных типов с битовыми полями на один.
Спасибо!

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct _dem_ram_data_{ // $DC
    union {
        struct {
            ViUInt64 errors     : 32;
            ViUInt64  addr      : 27;
            ViUInt64 _reserve    : 2;    
            ViUInt64 dataType    : 2;
            ViUInt64 graphEna    : 1;
        } vecAddr;
        struct {
            ViUInt64 tact       : 42;
            ViUInt64 _reserve   : 19;  
            ViUInt64 dataType    : 2;
            ViUInt64 graphEna    : 1;
        } tact;
         ViUInt64 d;  // data
    } demData;
    ViUInt32 cpl;
    ViUInt32 cph;
} DemRamData, *PDemRamData;
#pragma pack(pop)
```